# CSFR protection how to do it best without Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax

Info: I **don't** use Laravel.
In a post on stack I saw how you can protect yourself against `CSFR` .
Unfortunately, this contribution only related to a Laravel application and I'm not sure whether I can integrate it into my code just like that without using Laravel and if not whether there is another way to elegantly protect myself from `CSFR` ?

I'm not quite sure if it even makes a different using Laravel or not.
 Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>Newsletter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> // copied form the post
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({                                 // copied form the post start here
            headers:
                { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
            });                                           // copied form the post end here
            $("#newsletter-form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var thisemail = $("#newsletter-email").val();
            var thisdatenschutz = $("#newsletter-datenschutz").val();
            var thissubmit = $("#newsletter-submit").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "submitemail.php",
                data: {
                    email: thisemail,
                    datenschutz: thisdatenschutz,
                    submit: thissubmit
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data;
                    $("#newsletter-email").val("");
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
                }
            });
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: You'll need to generate your own tokens and validate the tokens on your backend. See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#token-based-mitigation

Comment: The CSRF token is just a random string that is stored in the session. The fact that the user knows this random string proves that they must have gotten it from a page that was generated in your code rather than somewhere else. It seems to be the [synchroniser token pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern)